# How to access communications API in Microsoft Graph

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api, botframework, microsoft-teams

I want to use the communications API in Microsoft Graph using a simple C# desktop app.

For now, let's say I want to use the GET /communications/calls/{id} request that can only be used via Application Permissions.

From my understanding, only bots can use the communications API.

So I've created a bot in Azure and deployed this code:

https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/24.bot-authentication-msgraph

The bot works and I get the user mail etc. but:

- The bot uses delegated credentials that are not supported for the Get Call request.
- I want to access the API via a C# desktop app using the bot credentials and not using the bot itself(I don't know if this is even possible but logic dictates that it should)

When I try a simple API request using the bot's app credintials (like I would use any other Azure app) I get this response:

> {"error":{"code":"UnknownError","message":"","innerError":{"date":"2022-03-31T09:29:44","request-id":"7906abfd-5ba4-439f-939c-42361c2ab255","client-request-id":"7906abfd-5ba4-439f-939c-42361c2ab255"}}}

which is not much help.

I've tried different ways like getting the JWT token for the bot and then using it to get an On-behalf-of provider as shown here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=CS and I get this exception:

`MsalUiRequiredException: AADSTS50058: A silent sign-in request was sent but no user is signed in.`

The code:

```
var scopes = new[] { "User.Read" };
var tenantId = "common";
var clientId = "appId";
var clientSecret = "appSecrete";
var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
{
     AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud
};
var oboToken = "JWT token I get form the bot with scope:appId/.default";
var cca = ConfidentialClientApplicationBuilder
     .Create(clientId)
     .WithTenantId(tenantId)
     .WithClientSecret(clientSecret)
     .Build();
var authProvider = new DelegateAuthenticationProvider(async (request) =>
{
     var assertion = new UserAssertion(oboToken);
     var result = await cca.AcquireTokenOnBehalfOf(scopes, assertion).ExecuteAsync();

     request.Headers.Authorization =
         new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", result.AccessToken);
});

var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(authProvider);

string callId = "callId";
var call = graphClient.Communications.Calls[$"{callId}"].Request().GetAsync();
call.Wait(); //-->here exception
var res = call.Result;
```

So firstly I want to know is it possible to use the communications API from a desktop app using the bot credentials?
If so then I would really appreciate a good explanation of a step-by-step on how to get the Get Call request to work,
specifically how to set up the bot, how to get the correct Access Token for the Graph API.
If not, I would appreciate a code example of using the Get Call API request from inside the bot.

Comment: Please have a look at this doc- 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/communications-api-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-comms-samples/
Let us know if you have any query.

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT I did look over it a few times and did not find the answers to my questions

Comment: If you want to Create Call, Join a call, Transfer/Redirect a call, Join a scheduled meeting and invite the participants by integrating cloud communications Graph API , then you can use this sample.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/bot-calling-meeting/csharp

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT thanks for the sample, it is useful I will try to strip the call commands to a non-bot desktop app